# How do we know and calculate in which direction and with what speed system of 2 person wrestling or pushing each other slide?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, velocity

We know that in wrestling or simply 2 people pushing each other , It doesn't matter how much force they apply on each other to know who will win or throw other away how because they both will experience same force (Newton 3 law), so what matter is how much force they apply on ground or floor or whatever they are standing on.

Moving on to doubt :- How will we know and calculate) in which direction the system of 2 people will move and with what speed if both people have different weight and are applying different force on ground.

Can anyone explain with an example and figures(any random value of force) of 2 people wrestling? Or something similar like this?

Comment: Do you know the concept of centre of mass of a system that the centre of mass of a system is at rest if there is no external force or all external forces cancel out?

Comment: No.. But how this tell answer of my doubt. BTW can I know in which class U r? 10th?

Comment: The question you have asked is related to this only because you are asking about the system of the two wrestlers and this can only be solved by the concept of centre of mass.

Comment: This is not the place to ask personal questions and I am not in class 10.

Comment: Sorry sir actually i thought it was my friend aditya so i though if he knew i could ansk him directly. Sorry again really really sorry

Answer (score 0):

Lets say two wrestlers are pushing eachother in opposite directions. Let the mass of wrestler one be $m_1$. Let the mass of the wrestler two be $m_2$. For wrestler one, the largest force he can apply against the other wrestler, is precisely the force of friction between his feet and the ground.

*(if the force was larger, then by Newtons third law, there would be an opposite force, pushing harder than the force of friction, and therefore he would begin to slip.)*

We can then calculate this force: $F_1=F_{f_1}=\mu\cdot F_{N_1}=\mu \cdot m_1 \cdot g$.

Let's now assume that there is the same gravitational acceleration on both of the wrestlers, and that the coeffecient of friction between their feet and the ground is the same. We can then calculate the force that wrestler two can apply to wrestler one: $F_2=F_{f_2}=\mu \cdot F_{N_2}=\mu \cdot m_2 \cdot g$.

We can now calculate the net force applied on the two wrestlers together: $F_{net}=F_1-F_2=\mu g(m_1-m_2)$.

From there, we can calculate the acceleration of the two restlers, since the mass is the sum of the two wrestlers.
$F_{net}=m_{tot}\cdot a\Rightarrow a=\frac{F_{net}}{m_{tot}}=\frac{\mu g(m_1-m_2)}{m_1+m_2}$.

Comment: Sir i found it great, just one more request i cannt understand the signs u have used can u simple it down in bracket (meaning of sign in simple word) as i am just a child of class 10. I mean answer in simlle meaning please.... If u have time please sir i am frustated by this que. IF!! Possible a rough diagram please, IF!!

Comment: $\mu$ is the coeffecient of friction between to materials (this is a value between 0 and 1, saying "how many percent of the normal force is being counted as frictional force"). This value is found experimentally. $F_N$ is the normal force on an object. Basically how much is the ground pushing on an object (to counterract gravity). g is just the gravitaitonal acceleration of earth $g=9,8 m/s^2$. Every time i used numbers, it is just for the different wrestlers.